# Azure active directory (AAD) authentication, redirect URL not working

Tags: azure, active-directory

I have implemented AAD authentication in one of my webapp, using OWIN. everything is working as expected on dev environment but it is not working on PROD. At login it goes to AAD page, it authenticate users and it redirects back to my registered page, but register page is not opening at all. In title it show working only. I am completely lost, how to resolve this, Please help me to resolve the same.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added the production reply URL? What page is it trying to go to after hitting AAD? Check the browser F12 tools to see where it is redirecting.

Comment: Yes i have added the PROD url as well. It is redirecting me on correct page, but that page is not behaving as expected on PROD.

Comment: Check your F12 tools, see what your app is responding, maybe set up remote debugging and debug your app?

Comment: Thanks juunas for your time and kind help here. I found a solution for this. Answered below.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. The issue was - to store the Tokens the Owin context created a local db (AzureTokenCache.mdf and .ldf files) in App_Data folder. This uses SQL express. Now we all know that using PaaS we cannot use any Software. Hence my authentication failed every time saying that error connecting to database. I moved everything to SQL Azure and it worked for me.